# Loop infinito em procedure

Tags: procedure, genexus

Tenho uma tabela `Categoria` com `CategoriaId` de primary key e `CategoriaPaiId` foreign key com auto-relacionamento em `CategoriaId`.

Eu preciso criar uma `procedure` que liste a arvore de categorias.

Supondo que eu tenho as categorias com suas respectivas subcategorias:
**Pereciveis > Bebidas > Vinhos > Tintos.**

No registro **Bebidas**, eu preciso que seja retornado na variável `&CategoriaSubCategoriaNome` a seguinte string:

**Pereciveis > Bebidas.**

No registro Tintos, eu preciso que seja retornado na variável `&CategoriaSubCategoriaNome` a seguinte string:

**Pereciveis > Bebidas > Vinhos**

Essa foi a procedure que eu imaginei:

```
&isTrue = true
&isAchou = true
do while &isTrue = true
    if &isAchou = true
            &isAchou = false    
            for each
                where CategoriaId = &CategoriaPaiId
                &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome = &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome+ " > " + CategoriaNome
                &isAchou = true
            endfor
        if &isAchou = false
            return
        endif
    endif
enddo
```

Porém ela está entrando em loop infinito.
Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito essa sintaxe, mas me parece que tu não esta mudando o valor de `&isTrue` em momento algum.

Em algum momento eu esperaria um `&isTrue=false` porque a condição do while está nesta variável. certo?!

Answer (score 0):

Esta procedure não faz a lógica de leitura dos dados de forma hierárquica. Ela pega um dado e retorna somente, ficando em loop se os dados forem encontrados.

O correto seria algo assim:

```
&CategoriaID = 10 // Por exemplo. Você precisa informar o ID inicial.
&CategoriaSubCategoriaNome.SetEmpty()

Do 'Processa estrutura'

Sub 'Processa estrutura'
    For each
        Where CategoriaId = &CategoriaID
            If Not &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome.IsEmpty()
                &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome = !' > ' + &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome
            EndIf
            &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome = CategoriaNome.Trim() + &CategoriaSubCategoriaNome
            If Not CategoriaPaiId.IsNull()
                &CategoriaId = CategoriaPaiId // ID da categoria Pai desta
                Do 'Processa estrutura'
            EndIf
    EndFor
EndSub
```